# Gitlab clone not working with new path setup

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitlab, bitnami

[Clone not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdCeq.png)

Gitlab: `bitnami-gitlab-8.1.3-0-linux-x64-installer.run`

Earlier, I have setup above mentioned gitlab in my local system in this path: `/var/www/html/ln-projects/gitlab/apps/gitlab/` but due to some reason, I have removed/uninstall that GitLab structure from that path.

Now, I have installed new gitlab in new other path: /opt/gitlab but now while taking clone of my first project I am facing above screenshot related issue.

I am not sure, it's related to OS issue or GitLab issue.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @KapilMaheshwari, regarding your edit: names of software (such as Ubuntu) are not themselves code, so they should not be formatted as such. They are [proper nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun), so an initial cap, or all-caps for acronyms, is fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you didn't uninstall completely the first gitlab stack and the servers for the second installation are not running or are running with non-default values.

In order to check which stack is running you can execute the following commands:

```
sudo /var/www/html/ln-projects/gitlab/ctlscript.sh status
sudo /opt/gitlab/ctlscript.sh status
```

Only one should be running and it should be the one installed at `/opt/gitlab`.

In order to clean the previous installation at `/var/www/html/ln-projects/gitlab` you can run the following commands:

```
$ sudo /var/www/html/ln-projects/gitlab/ctlscript.sh stop
$ sudo /var/www/html/ln-projects/gitlab/uninstall
```

And finally try to start the services from the new stack

```
$ sudo /opt/gitlab/ctlscript.sh start
```